# Function for lookup with multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel, function

[image]

I want a function that returns the Policy Number on "column A", by checking that client name on "column i" and client name on "column b" are the same and also cheeking if the claim date on "column J" is between the start date on "column C" and End date on "Column D". return it on Column H.

I am expecting a result by first looking on the client names are the same then checking if the claim date is between the start date and end date. Then the result to be shown on column H.

Comment: Index() with Match() should work - many exmples on here.

Comment: Please, post data example easy to copy/paste. You may use [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for it. Replicating your data manually consumes a lot of time so help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in H2 and drag down.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF((I2=B$2:B$7)*(J2>=C$2:C$7)*(J2<=D$2:D$7),A$2:A$7,""))
```

[image]